# Ожидание завершения процесса в Python

Tags: python

У меня есть процесс AutoIt.exe, у которого динамический id процесса. Как научить код ждать завершение процесса и после того, как процесс будет завершён, перейти к следующей строке кода?

Comment: А сейчас как вы вызываете процесс?

Comment: Использую команду os.startfile(r'Путь к скрипту AutoIt')

Comment: Используйте subprocess

Comment: Получается нужно написать subprocess.call(r"Путь к скрипту")?

Comment: Да, call сойдет, т.к. она ожидает завершения :)

Comment: Сработает ли это, если мне нужно запустить не программу, а скрипт?

Comment: Ага, но скорее всего нужно будет или через cmd запускать или в параметрах указать программу, типа python